# mongodb connection handling for multi-tenant architecture

Tags: mongodb

We are currently designing a SaaS application that has a subscriber/user based mode of operation. For example, a single subscriber can have 5, 10 or up to 25 users in their account dependent on what type of package they are on.

At the moment we are going with a single database per tenant approach. This has several advantages for us from the standpoint of the application.

I have read about the connection limits associated with Mongo and I am a little confused and worried. I was hoping someone could clarify it for me in simple terms, as I haven't worked much with Mongo.

From what I understand, there is a hard limit of 20,000 connections available on the mongod process and the mongos processes.

How does that translate to this multi-tenant approach? I am trying to basically asses how I would deploy the application in general in terms of replica sets and if sharding is necessary such that I don't hit these limits. How does one handle such a scenario for example if you have 10,000 tenants with multiple users that would exceed the limit.

Our application generally wouldn't need sharding as the each tenants collection wouldn't reach the point where it would need to be sharded. From what I understand though, MongoDB will create databases in a round robin fashion on each shard and will distribute the load which may help with the connection issues.

This is me just trying to make sense of what I've read and I'm hoping someone can clear this up for me.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

If I just add replica sets, will this alleviate this problem? Even though only the primary can accept writes from what I understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to store a database connection in a pool and reuse it if you access the same database again. This will limit the number of connections to a reasonable number unless you aren't using 10,000s of databases which wouldn't be a good idea anyway.

Comment: How does that resolve the problem though? If I am using connection pooling and the total active users exceeds the amount of connections that I can have in the pool then how does that scale? I am looking for an answer that evenly distributes the load without connection issues. This means that a single tenant per database multi-tenant approach in MongoDB has a hard limit, but I doubt that can possibly be the case. How do other others handle this architecture in terms of connections?

Comment: If you have 10,000s of tenants and every tenant has its own database and you want to handle this all with only one application server this won't work. You should overthink your database schema or you have to "shard" by yourself by handling tenants in groups on different servers --> tenant1-1000 on appServer1/dbServer1, tenant1001-2000 on appServer2/dbServer2 a.s.o.

Comment: This is what I am trying to actually find out. What type of network topology do I need to be able to achieve this result? Basically, the application doesn't need to be sharded from a collection perspective, but from what you are saying, from a tenant perspective then yes that needs to be the case.

Comment: If you store every tenant in a single database you will have at minimum one connection per tenant between the appserver and mongo. This forces you to limit the number of tenants per appserver and mongo instance. So you have to have multiple of them. At this point it is difficult to answer more specific on such a general question.